# OR clasue in a query using bookshelf

Tags: node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I want the users with `stateOne` or `stateTwo`, how can I do this using bookshelf?

This is what I got

```
User.where({id: req.user, state: 'stateOne'}).fetchAll().then((result) => {
        return res.json(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure if the below will work but it uses the `orWhere` operation.

```
User.query({
    where: {id: req.user, state: 'stateOne'}, 
    orWhere: {id: req.user, state: 'stateTwo'}
})
    .fetchAll()
    .then((result) => {
        return res.json(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

[Here is a link](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-query) to the documentation for reference